# How to add a custom header and then retrieve a custom header in rabbit message header

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, rawrabbit

I need to find a way to add an origin value in the custom header and then retrieve a custom header in the rabbit message header. Ideally, we should have it this way.

So far, I didn't have any success trying to find a way to do this.

```
Exchange    Test.Exchange
Routing Key Test.Exchange.7752275b-2323-42bf-98a4
Redelivered ●
Properties  user_id:fc4c-4d9c-9e4e-ad881040d0c1
type:   Events.Exchange
message_id: b2aff0d2-c8f4-4627-9826-089799bab344
delivery_mode:  2
headers:    global_execution_id:    7752275b-2323-42bf-98a4-ba7a8b96f2de
sent:   2019-04-30T13:54:24.4098945Z
**origin:   Test_Origin**

content_encoding:   UTF-8
content_type:   application/json

Payload30 bytesEncoding: string {"$id":"2","tenantId":"3456"}
```

Comment: Why storing an origin as a part of the message is not an option? It would make processing simpler and straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Directly from [the tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html):

> In the following example, we publish a message with custom headers:

```cs
byte[] messageBodyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, world!");

IBasicProperties props = model.CreateBasicProperties();
props.ContentType = "text/plain";
props.DeliveryMode = 2;
props.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
props.Headers.Add("latitude",  51.5252949);
props.Headers.Add("longitude", -0.0905493);

model.BasicPublish(exchangeName,
                   routingKey, props,
                   messageBodyBytes);
```

Comment: The question  is about RawRabbit package